# Количество просмотров статьи Django

Tags: python, django, django-orm

подскажите почему при открытии статьи добавляется 2 просмотра?

```
    def get_context_data(self,*,object_list=None,**kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        self.object.views = F("views") + 1
        self.object.save()
        self.object.refresh_from_db()
        context['cart']=self.cart
        return context
```

Comment: А что значит F("views")? Делал просто `blog_object.blog_views += 1`, а в модели поле `blog_views=models.IntegerField(default=0)`

Comment: в модели     views = models.IntegerField (default=0,verbose_name='Кол-во просмотров').
а во views
  class BlogDetail(CartMixin,DetailView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'blog-detail.html'
    context_object_name = 'post

Comment: обращась к атрибуту 'views' текущего обьекта 'post' а F('views')+1 выражение что там будет, сохраняю и перезапрашиваю данные

Comment: при принте показыает что я вызываю добавление 2 раза, подскажите что это может быть ?